# Most appropriate design for built in wardrobe - Long or short sections

Tags: mdf, particle-board, built-ins, melamine

I am going to tackle a set of built in wardrobes for our slightly-less-than standard width alcove. Annoyingly it is about 149cm wide whereas most wardrobes are 150! Silly new-build designers.

The space is **149 x 239cm (w x h)** and I currently have a standard 100cm wide Pax wardrobe in there just as a tie-over until I get something better sorted, and now is that time!

Thinking of something built in and a little more bespoke but in the same style of the Pax system - simple boxes with doors to house a clothing rail and a few shelves/drawers - I'm just wondering the best way to go about the longer span and the most appropriate materials to use.

Design-wise, I am not sure whether I should be doing 3 boxes of 48cm width each or whether to do 1 x 96cm and 1 x 48cm.

[image]
[image]

I've seen a lot of folks online use 18mm MDF for the carcasses but I'm worried about potential sagging of a longer stretch. Would this be something mitigated by using melamine chipboard instead? Or is MDF the strongest and bestest to go for?

I am planning on making these full height with internal shelves at the top like:

[image]

Is this something that would also need consideration for sagging etc?

Of course, all advice is welcome.

Comment: You seem determined to make all three spaces identical in width. There's little point. You could even chip the plaster off to give 150cm., and/or use the exising stopgap wardrobe, and build a 'half-size' one next to it, from the same or similar material.

Comment: Was hoping for a bit more of a starting from scratch viewpoint, to the specs I mentioned. If I was wanting to knock out the wall, I'd have been far further on with it all. I'm not using my existing wardobe as I'm wanting the doors to be all the same size.

Comment: That's fine, but size differences of a couple of cms really won't stick out, and in fact, if the centre is the different one, it'll look absolutely o.k. Personally, I think you're on a hiding for nothing.

Comment: I do love a good hiding. Wouldn't be a proper job if I didn't make it difficult for myself. I have to bleed at some point as well if I want bingo!

Comment: I am ignorant.  What is the advantage of a wardrobe in an alcove over a bar and shelves mounted to the walls of the alcove?

Comment: @Willk you assume that my walls are plumb and square ;-)